# Suitable use for Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I've asked to look into Microsoft Dynamics as a possible platform managing the state of factory equipment. Basically, we have hundreds of machines in our plant and we'd like track details regarding each machine, such as when it was installed, last back up time, next backup due, documents associated with each machine etc.  The app would also have to send out reminders to employees to perform backups etc.

Is this something Dynamics is suited to or are I better off contacting a software company to design a custom web app? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this particular requirement

> The app would also have to send out reminders to employees to perform
>   backups etc.

Can be done by Workflows.
Workflows simply are business processes executed behind the scene.

Please check this link for more information about Workflows and how they work, it will demonstrate the capabilities of Processes/Workflows.

[Automate Business Processes in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328264.aspx)

One more thing: You can go to [crm.dynamics.com](http://crm.dynamics.com) and create an online CRM Organization Demo to a test drive for the system if you really want to see and experiment the system.